# Laravel 5 Model: Do not include certain columns in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find an easier approach to this simple function I have. Basically what I am doing is dynamically loaded a form that's based on an Eloquent model. I do not want to include certain columns in the model like id's and the created_at and update_at columns. I am able to accomplish this with the following piece of code:

**get Controller:**

```
$cms_information = collect(CmsUserInformation::where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->toArray());

$cms_information->forget('id');
$cms_information->forget('users_id');
$cms_information->forget('created_at');
$cms_information->forget('updated_at');

$cms_information->all();

return view('cms::admin.profile', ['user' => Auth::user(), 'cms_information' => $cms_information]);
```

Then, I will loop through the fields in a form and post them like so:

**Post Controller:**

```
$profile = CmsUserInformation::where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

$cms_user_information = Input::except('_token', 'email', 'password');

foreach($cms_user_information as $field => $info ) {

    $profile->$field = $info;

}

$profile->save();
```

**My Eloquent table:**

```
id
user_id
first_name
last_name
email
created_at
updated_at
```

This works exactly how I want but I feel like it's a quick and dirty way around using the Eloquent object to accomplish this. Does anyone have a way to accomplish this same thing but only use Eloquent object rather than converting to an array and using the collect() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$hidden`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) property on your Eloquent model:

```php
class CmsUserInformation extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
        'users_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
}
```

This will automatically exclude the given attributes when the models are ultimately serialized.

---

If you only want to hide it in a specific instance, use the [`setHidden`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d15bc891d536c45d223082157198e64e3533e808/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2122-L2131) method:

```php
$info = CmsUserInformation::where('users_id', Auth::id())->first();

$info->setHidden([
    'id',
    'users_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make them hidden in all instances? I only want them hidden in this situation. Because i do use it when creating users also.

Comment: @Lynx - If you only want to do it for a particular model, use `setHidden` on it.

Comment: If I add the setHidden() at the end of the call it returns a null value. If I use setHidden do I need to add anything to the model?

Comment: @Lynx - I see now that `setHidden` doesn't return the model :( Simply break out the `setHidden` call off the chain. I updated the answer, and sent [a pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10399).

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden property in the model you are using like this:

```
class User extends Model{
    protected $hidden=[
               'id',
               'created_at',
               'updated_at'
    ];

...

}
```